# Getting informations from DB with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I want to get informations from a database, using PHP & Swift.

The program stops at the very last line of this code:

```
let post:NSString = "email=\(username)&password=\(password)"

NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://tatouapp.netau.net/login.php")!

let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = postData
request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


var reponseError: NSError?
var response: NSURLResponse?

let urlData: NSData? = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)

if ( urlData != nil ) {
    let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

    NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

    if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
    {
        let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

        let error: NSError?

        let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
```

I've got this error message:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

Comment: `JSON text did not start with array or object`: looks like the JSON is invalid (doesn't begin with `[` or `{`).

Comment: Replace force-unwrapping with safe unwrapping. Force unwrapping with `!` : the best way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @EdCottrell Done, very first post here, sorry :)

Comment: @Prométhéen Thanks; we've all been there!

Comment: @EricD. If I check contents of my variables, urlData value = {} et jsonData = {}